# How to find $\det(-6A)$, if $\det A=-4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I solve this?

> Assume that $A$ and $B$ are $6 \times 6$ matrices, such that $\det A = -4$ and $\det B = -2$. Find $\det(-6A)$.

Comment: The determinant of the $n\times n$ matrix $kA$ is $k^n$ times the determinant of $A$.

Comment: What is the purpose of the matrix $B$ here? What did you try?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Determinant is multi-linear for each column. Let $A=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. Thus $$\det(kA)=\det (ka_1,\ldots,ka_n)=k^n\det(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=k^n\det A$$

Answer (score 3):

If we can use the identity $\det(XY)=\det(X)\det(Y)$ for all square matrices $X_{n \times n},Y_{n \times n}$, then
\begin{align*}
 \det(-6A) &=\det(-6I \times A) \\
 &=\det(-6I)\det(A) \\
 &= \ldots.
\end{align*}